# Rendering a backbone js view to an attribute

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I want to append a backbone view to a `data-content` attribute on a div.  (Specifically, I want to send the view to a Bootstrap (v2.3.2) Popover).

Every time I try to set the attribute, I just see that the popover text contains an `[object HTMLDivElement]`  I want the HTML dynamically drawn to show in that data-content attribute.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: It'd help to see the Backbone code in question.

Comment: Why do you want to add view for single attribute? It is natural for backbone view to render a template into some element, to attach it with jQuery('el').html('...'). Probably it will be simpler to render attribute in whole popover view. Please provide code of your views.

Comment: So what I can do - is generate a view (it's not large - but it contains some dynamic HTML) into a hidden div, then set the contents of the data-content attribute to that HTML via a jquery selector.  That means the content of that view is inserted into the HTML twice - but I don't see that as an issue...

Answer (score 0):

For the data-content attribute, you need to set a String that has html. But not the HTML element. It will not be assigned that way by the view object of Backbone.

Comment: I agree - but can I create the HTML string from views and templates?  It's not a simple string - I want to construct a dynamic view in there...

Comment: you cannot pass views to data-content. Nor can u create string from views.. but u can definitely do it using templates